# Why does this code add key/value pair to browser.storage.local instead of overwriting it?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am pretty new to JavaScript. I am writing a Firefox extension at the moment where I am trying to make use of browser.storage.local. I am playing around with the following code that stems from the official Mozilla "webextensions-examples" GitHub repo (example: quicknote). It works perfectly fine, but I do not understand why I need to put the title in "[ ]" in order to add a new key/value pair to the local storage. If I leave the brackets out, the local storage is simply overwritten, even if I am using a different key/value pair than before. Here is the code snippet:

```
function storeNote(title, body) {
  var storingNote = browser.storage.local.set({ [title] : body });
  storingNote.then(() => {
    displayNote(title,body);
  }, onError);
}
```

Why is that? Thanks for help!

Comment: Brackets (`[ ]`) on the left-hand side of the `:` in an object initializer indicate that the property name should be the value of the expression inside `[ ]`. Otherwise, the property name would always just be "title".

Comment: Ahhh, now I get it... it's so simple, thanks! I thought that it would use the argument passed to the function.